# How likely is a difference of final conversion between two randomly split groups who have passed the same sales funnel?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

I'm having a discussion with a friend regarding an interview question (neither of us got the job :):
An ecommerce gets 40,000 visitors on 1 day. They are randomly split into 2 groups (A/B) of 20 000 each. And by the end of the day it's measured that group A purchased for \$442,000 and group B purchased for \$408,000. How probable is this outcome, in as plain English as possible? (we're obviously not statisticians)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give an answer which doesn't require statistical knowledge.

On average, group A spend \$11.05 each and group B \$10.20 each. How plausible this difference is will depend on the variance in how much visitors spend on the site per visit.

For an extreme high variance case, if the site sells extremely expensive cars, then maybe only two purchases in total were made: a single person in group A bought a \$442,000 car, and a single person in group B bought a \$408,000 car. These data wouldn't be surprising.

For an extreme low variance case, suppose that every visitor spends either exactly \$10.20 or exactly \$11.05. For the numbers to add up, everybody in group A would have had to spend \$11.05 and everybody in group B \$10.20 - which is extremely unlikely to happen by chance.

If you knew the sample variance, you could use [statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) to quantify how suspicious the difference in mean spending between the groups is. (It's possible that the interviewer was expecting you to make a guess about what the sample variance might plausibly be based on your intuition about visitor behaviour patterns on ecommerce websites.)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, we do know those things, I was too quick. We know that 3360 purchased in A and 3570 in B. We also know stddev is 118400 in A and 120900 in B. Can we then get an exact answer? And what method would you use?